# How to use ExtAudioFileWrite

Tags: swift, core-audio, extaudiofile

▿ AudioStreamBasicDescription

- mSampleRate : 44100.0
- mFormatID : 1819304813
- mFormatFlags : 41
- mBytesPerPacket : 4
- mFramesPerPacket : 1
- mBytesPerFrame : 4
- mChannelsPerFrame : 8
- mBitsPerChannel : 32
- mReserved : 0

checkErr(ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(fileUrl as CFURL, kAudioFileCAFType, &asbd, nil, AudioFileFlags.eraseFile.rawValue, &fileId))

When I  call ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL  use the above AudioStreamBasicDescription configuration is always to quote the following error. I didn't know there was a problem

ExtAudioFile.cpp:329   about to throw 'fmt?': create audio file

Comment: mFormatID : 1819304813 is  kAudioFormatLinearPCM